# Getting user agent value. Server side vs Client side?

Tags: javascript, php, server, client, user-agent

I need to pass user agent value into front end.

I can get this value using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and write it into front end.
(Actually I will be using  `Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent()`, but I think it's just a magento helper to call above mentioned function.)

Or I can use get `navigator.userAgent` with js on client side.

Which better and why? My primary concern is speed.

p.s. I understand that UA can be easily manipulated. We are not basing any serious functionality on the value, it's used as a secondary parameter.

Comment: If you're passing it into the front end and can get it from the front end, why use the server at all?

Comment: From the SO Close Reasons - *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."* You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally use `navigator.userAgent`. Mainly, because passing values from PHP to JavaScript is pretty ugly in my opinion. Also, the value will be exactly the same for both. Even if someone decides to edit their useragent.

I think simplicity takes the cake here.

Comment: I make use of a chrome extension to switch my user agent to the one of a google bot. The `navigator.userAgent` is not updating, although when testing the same thing with puppeteer it works.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will depend on the purpose. If you need this inside php, then use the server variable with helper getter you mentioned above. For js use navigator object.

In general both navigator.userAgent and HTTP_USER_AGENT are variables of Request Header and are both already present in memory (of server or users browser in case of js). So no measurable performance difference is possible.